# How do I achieve passwordless CVS updates?

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, cvs, ssh-keys

I'm working on some code from my computer at home and would like to do CVS updates to a remote server. When I'm at work I don't need to type in a password, but at home each time I need to type in my password each time I do a CVS update.

I've followed the instructions here on how to set up a passwordless public/private ssh key pair: http://www.ece.uci.edu/~chou/ssh-key.html

However, after that I still need to type in my ssh password each time I do CVS update (or anything CVS related) from my local computer.

What am I missing?

Comment: Ok, now it says "ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host" whenever I try to do a CVS from my local machine. I've had this problem before when messing around with ssh keys and usually after 24 hours I can access the server again. I'll try again tomorrow but I'll still have that problem with having to type in my password each time

Comment: see below - how do the permissions of ~/.ssh/authorized_keys look like? Don't give anyone except the user write permission, or the SSH daemon will refuse to accept that (security risk - anyone could paste in his key if he can write to the file)

Answer (score 1):

What you did was setting up SSH authentication, and that works for everything using SSH as transport. As long as you are using the :ssh: method it should work for CVS to.

Have look at the CVS/Root file inside a checked out directory to see what access method you are using, it should say

```
:ext:jrandom@cvs.foobar.com:
```

for transport over SSH.

Comment: Yep, mine says :ext:user@remotehost.com:/home/cvs

Comment: funny. What does interactively connecting with SSH say? Does that work without a pasword? If not, do the permissions of the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys only allow "w" for the user?